# User Defined Print area in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a Pretty way for a Customized Print area in Excel.
I Have a big Excel list where many Users work with.
What i want is, that every User can make a Custom Print out quick and easy.
I don't have andy Problem with the Code to define a print area in excel.
Where I'm Struggling is a Pretty Solution for that.

I thought about  Something Like in the Image below with Checkboxes. But that does not convince me really.

**Does anyone of you know any better Solution for that Problem? Any Hints are Welcome.**

[image]

Comment: with Pretty you mean visually attractive, or clean code?

Comment: And what are the options people can choose from, only these 5 columns you show in the picture?

Comment: In the Original File there are 24 Columns with diffrent data

Comment: And when they want to print they always want to print the entire columns?

Comment: yes they want to print the entire Coloumn

Comment: Then I would make in a new worksheet a list with the checkboxes you have. With the names of the columns, or the headers if there are any present, in column A and checkboxes in column B. Otherwise you would end up with either putting in 1 or 0 in a list whether to print or not as being binary options, or manually inputting the numbers of the columns you want to print into a list.

Comment: Going along with that, it might be better to setup the print sheet, then have the user select the columns and hit a button that calls the code to move the selected columns. This way it could also know how many there are and what other resizing it needs to do to the print sheet.

Comment: ok. will give both Options a change and try them